# How to get list of locales in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, locale

I would like to give user option to select text file locale.

Is there some class in .net that keeps list of available locales?

Now, I am planning to make my own list class from MSDN page: [Language Identifier Constants and Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693(VS.85).aspx), but it would be nicer if there is something already in .net.

Here is MSDN article on [CultureInfo.GetCultures method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx) that Jeremy wrote in his answer. There are also code examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd want like a 'for each locale loop'.

```
    Dim info As CultureInfo
    For Each info In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(info.EnglishName)
    Next
```

Takes like half a second to dump a list of locales into the Listbox1

Then you can reference 'info' in various ways such as:

```
    info.NumberFormat
    info.DateTimeFormat
```

Get todays date in that locales date:

```
        If Not info.IsNeutralCulture Then
            Dim dateNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dateNow.ToString("d", info.DateTimeFormat).ToString)
        End If
```

Comment: Your welcome. Make sure you use the IsNeutralCulture check otherwise you will cause exceptions when converting locale data.

Answer (score 2):

check out everything around the [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) class. you'll probably find there what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures?view=net-7.0) to get list of all cu

```
foreach (var locale in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(locale);
}
```