# List of all available languages for Windows .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, localization, locale, globalization

I've been searching for the answer over the net, but I don't seem to be able to find a comprehensive list of all languages available for my app with their exact display name. (I find many lists, but none of them seem to match the language strings I have. Read on.) The closest one I found is [this one,](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/sharepoint-supported-languages-culture.html) but is not complete.

I am coding a plugin in C# where the text is exported from SDL Trados Studio to Word and the language is set accordingly in Word.

I need to write a custom method that casts these language names to their relevant `Word.Language` equivalent. This is because Trados (using the Windows cultures and .NET framework 4.5) has different language (locale) names than the `Word.Language` names.

While **Hungarian** is the same, **TraditionalChinese** (`Word.Language`) is **Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)** in Trados.

I do have a comprehensive list for `Word.Languages` already:

```cs
public static class LanguageList
{
    public static readonly HashSet<LanguageItem> _languageList = new HashSet<LanguageItem>(new[]
    {
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Saudi Arabia)", 1025),
        new LanguageItem("Bulgarian", 1026),
        new LanguageItem("Catalan", 1027),
        new LanguageItem("Chinese (Taiwan)", 1028),
        new LanguageItem("Czech", 1029),
        new LanguageItem("Danish", 1030),
        new LanguageItem("German (Germany)", 1031),
        new LanguageItem("Greek", 1032),
        new LanguageItem("English (U.S.)", 1033),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Spain-Traditional Sort)", 1034),
        new LanguageItem("Finnish", 1035),
        new LanguageItem("French (France)", 1036),
        new LanguageItem("Hebrew", 1037),
        new LanguageItem("Hungarian", 1038),
        new LanguageItem("Icelandic", 1039),
        new LanguageItem("Italian (Italy)", 1040),
        new LanguageItem("Japanese", 1041),
        new LanguageItem("Korean", 1042),
        new LanguageItem("Dutch (Netherlands)", 1043),
        new LanguageItem("Norwegian (Bokmål)", 1044),
        new LanguageItem("Polish", 1045),
        new LanguageItem("Portuguese (Brazil)", 1046),
        new LanguageItem("Rhaeto-Romanic", 1047),
        new LanguageItem("Romanian (Romania)", 1048),
        new LanguageItem("Russian (Russia)", 1049),
        new LanguageItem("Croatian", 1050),
        new LanguageItem("Slovak", 1051),
        new LanguageItem("Albanian", 1052),
        new LanguageItem("Swedish (Sweden)", 1053),
        new LanguageItem("Thai", 1054),
        new LanguageItem("Turkish", 1055),
        new LanguageItem("Urdu", 1056),
        new LanguageItem("Indonesian", 1057),
        new LanguageItem("Ukrainian", 1058),
        new LanguageItem("Belarusian", 1059),
        new LanguageItem("Slovenian", 1060),
        new LanguageItem("Estonian", 1061),
        new LanguageItem("Latvian", 1062),
        new LanguageItem("Lithuanian", 1063),
        new LanguageItem("Tajik", 1064),
        new LanguageItem("Farsi", 1065),
        new LanguageItem("Vietnamese", 1066),
        new LanguageItem("Armenian", 1067),
        new LanguageItem("Azeri (Latin)", 1068),
        new LanguageItem("Basque", 1069),
        new LanguageItem("Sorbian", 1070),
        new LanguageItem("FYRO Macedonian", 1071),
        new LanguageItem("Sutu", 1072),
        new LanguageItem("Tsonga", 1073),
        new LanguageItem("Tswana", 1074),
        new LanguageItem("Venda", 1075),
        new LanguageItem("Xhosa", 1076),
        new LanguageItem("Zulu", 1077),
        new LanguageItem("Afrikaans", 1078),
        new LanguageItem("Georgian", 1079),
        new LanguageItem("Faeroese", 1080),
        new LanguageItem("Hindi", 1081),
        new LanguageItem("Maltese", 1082),
        new LanguageItem("Sami (Lappish)", 1083),
        new LanguageItem("Gaelic (Scotland)", 1084),
        new LanguageItem("Yiddish", 1085),
        new LanguageItem("Malay", 1086),
        new LanguageItem("Kazakh", 1087),
        new LanguageItem("Kyrgyz", 1088),
        new LanguageItem("Swahili", 1089),
        new LanguageItem("Turkmen", 1090),
        new LanguageItem("Uzbek (Latin)", 1091),
        new LanguageItem("Tatar", 1092),
        new LanguageItem("Bengali", 1093),
        new LanguageItem("Punjabi", 1094),
        new LanguageItem("Gujarati", 1095),
        new LanguageItem("Oriya", 1096),
        new LanguageItem("Tamil", 1097),
        new LanguageItem("Telugu", 1098),
        new LanguageItem("Kannada", 1099),
        new LanguageItem("Malayalam", 1100),
        new LanguageItem("Assamese", 1101),
        new LanguageItem("Marathi", 1102),
        new LanguageItem("Sanskrit", 1103),
        new LanguageItem("Mongolian", 1104),
        new LanguageItem("Tibetan (PRC)", 1105),
        new LanguageItem("Welsh", 1106),
        new LanguageItem("Khmer", 1107),
        new LanguageItem("Lao", 1108),
        new LanguageItem("Burmese", 1109),
        new LanguageItem("Galician", 1110),
        new LanguageItem("Konkani", 1111),
        new LanguageItem("Manipuri", 1112),
        new LanguageItem("Sindhi (Devanagari)", 1113),
        new LanguageItem("Syriac", 1114),
        new LanguageItem("Sinhalese", 1115),
        new LanguageItem("Cherokee", 1116),
        new LanguageItem("Inuktitut", 1117),
        new LanguageItem("Amharic", 1118),
        new LanguageItem("Tamazight", 1119),
        new LanguageItem("Kashmiri (Arabic)", 1120),
        new LanguageItem("Nepali", 1121),
        new LanguageItem("Frisian (Netherlands)", 1122),
        new LanguageItem("Pashto", 1123),
        new LanguageItem("Filipino", 1124),
        new LanguageItem("Divehi", 1125),
        new LanguageItem("Edo", 1126),
        new LanguageItem("Fulfulde", 1127),
        new LanguageItem("Hausa", 1128),
        new LanguageItem("Ibibio", 1129),
        new LanguageItem("Yoruba", 1130),
        new LanguageItem("Quechua (Bolivia)", 1131),
        new LanguageItem("Sepedi", 1132),
        new LanguageItem("Bashkir (Russia)", 1133),
        new LanguageItem("Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)", 1134),
        new LanguageItem("Greenlandic (Greenland)", 1135),
        new LanguageItem("Igbo", 1136),
        new LanguageItem("Kanuri", 1137),
        new LanguageItem("Oromo", 1138),
        new LanguageItem("Tigrigna (Ethiopia)", 1139),
        new LanguageItem("Guarani", 1140),
        new LanguageItem("Hawaiian", 1141),
        new LanguageItem("Latin", 1142),
        new LanguageItem("Somali", 1143),
        new LanguageItem("Yi", 1144),
        new LanguageItem("Papiamentu", 1145),
        new LanguageItem("Mapudungun (Chile)", 1146),
        new LanguageItem("Mohawk (Mohawk)", 1148),
        new LanguageItem("Breton (France)", 1150),
        new LanguageItem("Uyghur (PRC)", 1152),
        new LanguageItem("Maori", 1153),
        new LanguageItem("Occitan (France)", 1154),
        new LanguageItem("Corsican (France)", 1155),
        new LanguageItem("Alsatian (France)", 1156),
        new LanguageItem("Yakut (Russia)", 1157),
        new LanguageItem("K'iche (Guatemala)", 1158),
        new LanguageItem("Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)", 1159),
        new LanguageItem("Wolof (Senegal)", 1160),
        new LanguageItem("Dari (Afghanistan)", 1164),
        new LanguageItem("Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)", 1169),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Iraq)", 2049),
        new LanguageItem("Chinese (PRC)", 2052),
        new LanguageItem("German (Switzerland)", 2055),
        new LanguageItem("English (U.K.)", 2057),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Mexico)", 2058),
        new LanguageItem("French (Belgium)", 2060),
        new LanguageItem("Italian (Switzerland)", 2064),
        new LanguageItem("Dutch (Belgium)", 2067),
        new LanguageItem("Norwegian (Nynorsk)", 2068),
        new LanguageItem("Portuguese (Portugal)", 2070),
        new LanguageItem("Romanian (Moldova)", 2072),
        new LanguageItem("Russian (Moldova)", 2073),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Latin)", 2074),
        new LanguageItem("Swedish (Finland)", 2077),
        new LanguageItem("Azeri (Cyrillic)", 2092),
        new LanguageItem("Lower Sorbian (Germany)", 2094),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Northern (Sweden)", 2107),
        new LanguageItem("Gaelic (Ireland)", 2108),
        new LanguageItem("Malay (Brunei Darussalam)", 2110),
        new LanguageItem("Uzbek (Cyrillic)", 2115),
        new LanguageItem("Bengali (Bangladesh)", 2117),
        new LanguageItem("Punjabi (Pakistan)", 2118),
        new LanguageItem("Mongolian (Mongolian)", 2128),
        new LanguageItem("Tibetan (Bhutan)", 2129),
        new LanguageItem("Sindhi (Arabic)", 2137),
        new LanguageItem("Inuktitut (Latin, Canada)", 2141),
        new LanguageItem("Tamazight (Latin)", 2143),
        new LanguageItem("Kashmiri", 2144),
        new LanguageItem("Nepali (India)", 2145),
        new LanguageItem("Quechua (Ecuador)", 2155),
        new LanguageItem("Tigrigna (Eritrea)", 2163),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Egypt)", 3073),
        new LanguageItem("Chinese (Hong Kong S.A.R.)", 3076),
        new LanguageItem("German (Austria)", 3079),
        new LanguageItem("English (Australia)", 3081),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Spain-Modern Sort)", 3082),
        new LanguageItem("French (Canada)", 3084),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Cyrillic)", 3098),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Northern (Finland)", 3131),
        new LanguageItem("Quechua (Peru)", 3179),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Libya)", 4097),
        new LanguageItem("Chinese (Singapore)", 4100),
        new LanguageItem("German (Luxembourg)", 4103),
        new LanguageItem("English (Canada)", 4105),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Guatemala)", 4106),
        new LanguageItem("French (Switzerland)", 4108),
        new LanguageItem("Croatian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)", 4122),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Lule (Norway)", 4155),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Algeria)", 5121),
        new LanguageItem("Chinese (Macao S.A.R.)", 5124),
        new LanguageItem("German (Liechtenstein)", 5127),
        new LanguageItem("English (New Zealand)", 5129),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Costa Rica)", 5130),
        new LanguageItem("French (Luxembourg)", 5132),
        new LanguageItem("Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)", 5146),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Lule (Sweden)", 5179),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Morocco)", 6145),
        new LanguageItem("English (Ireland)", 6153),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Panama)", 6154),
        new LanguageItem("French (Monaco)", 6156),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)", 6170),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Southern (Norway)", 6203),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Tunisia)", 7169),
        new LanguageItem("English (South Africa)", 7177),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Dominican Republic)", 7178),
        new LanguageItem("French (West Indies)", 7180),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)", 7194),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Southern (Sweden)", 7227),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Oman)", 8193),
        new LanguageItem("English (Jamaica)", 8201),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Venezuela)", 8202),
        new LanguageItem("French (Reunion)", 8204),
        new LanguageItem("Bosnian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)", 8218),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Skolt (Finland)", 8251),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Yemen)", 9217),
        new LanguageItem("English (Caribbean)", 9225),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Colombia)", 9226),
        new LanguageItem("French (Congo (DRC))", 9228),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Latin, Serbia)", 9242),
        new LanguageItem("Sami, Inari (Finland)", 9275),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Syria)", 10241),
        new LanguageItem("English (Belize)", 10249),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Peru)", 10250),
        new LanguageItem("French (Senegal)", 10252),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)", 10266),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Jordan)", 11265),
        new LanguageItem("English (Trinidad and Tobago)", 11273),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Argentina)", 11274),
        new LanguageItem("French (Cameroon)", 11276),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)", 11290),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Lebanon)", 12289),
        new LanguageItem("English (Zimbabwe)", 12297),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Ecuador)", 12298),
        new LanguageItem("French (Cote d'Ivoire)", 12300),
        new LanguageItem("Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)", 12314),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Kuwait)", 13313),
        new LanguageItem("English (Philippines)", 13321),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Chile)", 13322),
        new LanguageItem("French (Mali)", 13324),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (U.A.E)", 14337),
        new LanguageItem("English (Indonesia)", 14345),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Uruguay)", 14346),
        new LanguageItem("French (Morocco)", 14348),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Bahrain)", 15361),
        new LanguageItem("English (Hong Kong S.A.R.)", 15369),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Paraguay)", 15370),
        new LanguageItem("French (Haiti)", 15372),
        new LanguageItem("Arabic (Qatar)", 16385),
        new LanguageItem("English (India)", 16393),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Bolivia)", 16394),
        new LanguageItem("English (Malaysia)", 17417),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (El Salvador)", 17418),
        new LanguageItem("English (Singapore)", 18441),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Honduras)", 18442),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Nicaragua)", 19466),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (Puerto Rico)", 20490),
        new LanguageItem("Spanish (United States)", 21514),
    });

    public static LanguageItem GetLanguageItem(string languageName)
    {
        return _languageList.SingleOrDefault(li => li.Name.Equals(languageName));
    }
}
```

I am trying to find a comprehensive list of the locales used in the Windows cultures. The key point is that **zh-TW** needs to be **Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)** and not something else. I did not manage to find such a list despite extensive searching already.

**Edit:**

1. To clarify, my question is, how to retrieve the the exact list in my code? I believe it is should be somewhere in the Windows cultures, such as `CultureInfo.DisplayName` or similar. Any idea?
2. What is the most effective method then to cast them over to the `Word.LanguageID`?

**Update:**
See answer posted below for my solution to these questions. Still would appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: The list you are looking for is based on the ISO 693 standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) which has changed over time and which will change again I assume. Also, this is not a programming question: you are looking for a resource ;-)

Comment: Nice thing about ISO is they provide so many standards to choose from.

Comment: [Appendix F - Country/Region and Language Codes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346950.aspx).

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Thanks a lot. This is not the list I need it does not match the strings I get. See updated question, I made it more clear. I also made some progress in the meantime in retrieving a similar (maybe the same?) list, with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2260589/6201755 So it is now getting to be the problem really to cast them over to `Word.LangaugeID`

Comment: @HansPassant Yup, with none of them matching...

Comment: @poke Same with this one, I saw this one, and this is not the list I need. But see updated Question.

Comment: ...where did you get the exact list in your code?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Your comment was very useful. I looked closer, and noted that it was an oversight to just use the enumeration. So I corrected the code using this: `foreach (Word.Language item in oWord.Application.Languages) { Debug.WriteLine("new LanguageItem(\"" + item.NameLocal + "\", " + ((int)item.ID).ToString() + "),"); }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The complete list of all languages can be returned from `CultureInfo`:

```cs
using System.Globalization;
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(culture.EnglishName);
}
```

As in this post: [Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies)

And as [covered on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GetAll).

And after extensive searching and testing, I found that the language collection that is used by the SDL Trados Studio is the `CultureInfo`.

It is accessed through the API as:

```cs
string strTgtLocaleId = EditorController.ActiveDocument.ActiveFile.Language.ToString();
string strTgtLanguage = EditorController.ActiveDocument.ActiveFile.Language.DisplayName.ToString();
int intTgtLanguageId = EditorController.ActiveDocument.ActiveFile.Language.CultureInfo.LCID;
```

Thus the full list actually that I need for my plugin (acknowledging @Jenszcz's observation on the legacy strings from earlier products) is in fact can be enumerated from the `CultureInfo`.

My goal was however to directly translate these codes to the Word version of the IDs. So I ran a code to compare the two lists. I used the `Word.Language` enumeration that I posted in the OP:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            //OBJECTS OF FALSE AND TRUE
            Object oTrue = true;
            Object oFalse = false;


            //CREATING OBJECTS OF WORD AND DOCUMENT
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();

            var test = oWord.Application.Languages;

            foreach (var item in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures))
            {
                if (LanguageList._languageList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(item.LCID)) != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(LanguageList._languageList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(item.LCID)).Name +
                        " -- " +
                        item.EnglishName +
                        " -- " +
                        ((int)item.LCID).ToString()
                    );
                }
                else if (LanguageList._languageList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(item.Parent.LCID)) != null)
                {
                    Debug.Indent();
                    Debug.WriteLine("-------- PARENT MATCH: " + item.EnglishName + " -- " + ((int)item.Parent.LCID).ToString());
                    Debug.Unindent();
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Indent();
                    Debug.WriteLine("!!!!!!!! NO MATCH: " + item.EnglishName + " -- " + ((int)item.LCID).ToString());
                    Debug.Unindent();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And the result was very lucky for me. In fact the `Word.WdLanguageID` matched all the `CultureInfo.LCID` values one for one, except for the legacy and exotic locales (which is not needed for my plugin).

Therefore I ended up not even needing the list of language strings returned by `item.EnglishName` such as **Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)**.

So I skipped the enumeration whole cloth. The code now runs in milliseconds as compared to the minutes it originally took to loop through all languages in the `Word.Languages`. I used the following code to set the language in the Word Document:

```cs
try
{
    oWord.Selection.LanguageID = (Word.WdLanguageID)intTgtLanguageId;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    oWord.Selection.LanguageID = (Word.WdLanguageID)0;
}
```

This sets all matching languages, casting the `LCID` to the correct `Word.WdLanguageID` constant. For those that are not matched, it sets it to "Not set".

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for Microsoft's Locale ID (LCID) list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx

Answer (score 0):

These strings are probably taken from SDL Studio embedded resources, from Sdl.LanguagePlatform.Lingua.dll. I did a quick try to locate your Taiwanese example, but it did not work. Still, to show you how not to do it, here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // forced enum iteration
        for (int n = 0; n < 6; ++n)
        {
            var localInfoSet = Sdl.LanguagePlatform.Lingua.Locales.LocaleInfoSet.GetLocaleInfoSet((Sdl.LanguagePlatform.Lingua.Locales.LocaleSource)n);

            var tradLocaleInfo = localInfoSet.Where(item => item.Name.Contains("Traditional,"));
            foreach (var item in tradLocaleInfo)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I deliberately left the full namespaces in instead of `using` them. Perhaps this can serve you as a starting point to get access to those lists. Or perhaps not, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is this collection exposed by the API? Maybe that's with it returned nothing. But this may be a good path to look.

Comment: These collections can be accessed through the .NET interface of the dll, but you may not reference the dll in Studio plugins, if that's what you're trying to do. A text search will show you that the dll does contain the string `Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)`, but I did not figure out how to get there through the entry points provided by SDL.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not come up with any way to access these resources in a way intended by SDL. And if you want to publish a plug-in for Studio you probably do not want to reverse-engineer the Studio dlls. Perhaps you could ask the [SDL community developers](https://community.sdl.com/developers/language-developers/) ?

Comment: Of course not, however it seems to me that these language codes are coming from the `CultureInfo` object, so I don't think they are SDL proprietary.

Comment: You are right: some of these names (and codes) come from  `CultureInfo` objects from different Windows versions. However, others come from earlier products (SDLX  and Trados Workbench). That's what the enum `Sdl.LanguagePlatform.Lingua.Locales.LocaleSource` has been put in for, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your help! See my posted answer.