# WPF - get the list of Windows 10 languages

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

In C# WPF, how to get the list of Windows 10 available languages, I need this to load the dropdown list in WPF.

I see this is available in UWP but I don't find one for WPF. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2954327-fe9e-484e-95bf-e6b1e3f32858/uwp-howto-show-language-list-with-installed-input-languages-at-the-top?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all available languages for Windows .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244656/list-of-all-available-languages-for-windows-net-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this *NuGet Package* [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) so you can access [Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences) from WPF.

Then you can call this code from your WPF Application:

```
var languages = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages.ToList();
```

It will contain a list of string of languages that are preferred by the user, in order of preference. On my machine, it returns "pt-BR":

[image: Culture]

References: 
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/calling-windows-10-apis-from-a-desktop-application-just-got-easier/#eAjFgDgbqEcJZIqb.97

Note that it requires default package management format set to **PackageReference**, and *NuGet* 4.0 or higher.

You can do it on Visual Studio 2019 using the context menu:
[image: Screenshot]